# Use divs to create something similar to iframe

Tags: html

A question recently came up in my programming class as to whether it would be possible to create something similar to an iframe but using only divs and javascript/css. The instructor said it was possible, but since I'm new to the whole deal of programming I'm at a loss as to how to write such code. Does anyone have a quick example as to how this would be done?

Comment: 'similar' in what way?

Comment: You can simulate the scroll bars in a div with `overflow:scroll;` but that's about all I know!

Comment: Probably you could load another page inside div using AJAX.

Answer (score 1):

If you're talking about displaying external content in the page without the use of an iframe, you can use AJAX to load content from another page or even from a service and render it into a div. See [this explanation and demo on CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/ajax-load-container-contents/).

Answer (score 0):

Most likely your instructor was thinking of using something like

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:scroll;"></div>
```

Or

```
<div style="width:500px;height:500px;overflow:auto;"></div>
```

Both of which can be used to produce a fixed-size div with scroll bar overflow.  You can even load content from another page using AJAX and insert it into the div. However, unlike an iframe, they cannot be used to display content from another domain (unless it allows CORS.)

Comment: How did you even deduce that the asker is asking about simulating physical properties of an `iframe` such as scrollbars and not other functional properties? There can be `iframe`s without scrollbars ಠ_ಠ

Comment: Because FULLY replicating the functionality of an iframe using divs is impossible, and I would assume their instructor would know that. Scroll/auto overflow is the closest to an iframe a div can get.

Comment: For a partial support, you could get the body of another HTML page using AJAX and set the `innerHTML` of the target div to that. For somewhat full support you could inject the scripts and stylesheets into the head of current page.

Answer (score 0):

I would say it is possible and iframe is essentially embedding a content resource from another location be it on the local domain or external domain. Replicating this could be easy or difficult in the type of request you are wanting to make a simple way using jquery would be to have something like this
    
    
     $.ajax({ url: urlToResource, success:function(data){
      $('.contentDiv').html(data);
    });

```
<style type="text/css">
.contentDiv {
 overflow:auto;
 width:200px;
 height:200px;
}
</style>

<div class="contentDiv"></div>
```

Again this is all dependant on what type of resource and whether the remote domain has an ajax block on it there would be another way to get round this though with a simple php file;

```
<?php

  print file_get_contents("http:://pathToResource.com");

?>
```

That should be enough to start investigating yourself. But as a tip try and avoid ever using iFrames they are more hassle than they are worth and are quite dated in regards to current technologies such as html5 etc.

Comment: HTML5 includes `iframe`s, and in fact, has *enhanced* them. Sure, they may not be useful in all cases, but one thing they're *excellent* at is sandboxing.

Comment: im not saying that they dont belong anywhere but they can be a hassle an easy work around can be implemented.